# int_max in 32 bit vs 64 bit environment

Tags: c, int, c99

Is `INT_MAX` different between a 32-bit and 64-bit environment? It seems like it would be the case, though I've heard people say that the 64-bit environment just uses the 32-bit environment's INT_MAX.

Comment: There is no such thing like *a* 32-bit or 64-bit environment, but there are multiple definitions for each such systems.

Answer (score 6):

It depends on the system.  On Intel Linux they are the same.  check `limits.h`

Comment: Is there a good resource I might be able to look up on understanding how they're the same on an Intel processor (and where, perhaps, they may differ instead?). Thanks!

Comment: you typically account for differences using preprocessor or by using stdint.h  what is exactly u look for?

Comment: Trying to see what happens with underflow on an `unsigned long long int`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2760502/question-about-c-behaviour-for-unsigned-integer-underflow

Comment: I'd say it actually depends on the compiler, which in turn is usually tuned for a specific system (CPU/OS).

Answer (score 0):

Your question is perhaps too generic, but on typical 64bit enviroment (x86-64) int is defacto the same size as on 386 (keeping in mind that this also depends on OS, not just architecture). C standard only limits lower bounds (as described on [wiki](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C_Programming/C_Reference/limits.h)).

Comment: How does it depend on the OS? I'm sorry if it seemed so generic - I haven't been able to find good resources on INT_MAX in general.

Comment: When you get 32bit linux on x86-64, OS will use 32bit limits (ULOG_MAX changes for example).

Answer (score 0):

For some compilers, there is a difference with the `long` type. That is, `long` is 32 bits when compiling for 32 bits and 64 bits otherwise, while `int` is 32 bits in both cases.

But depending on what you want, the answer to your question may be to use `int64_t` (or the equivalent for your compiler, maybe `__int64` or something like that) if you want to make sure you have a 64-bit int.

So you should clarify your question.

Comment: How about if I used `unsigned long long int`? Will INT_MAX differ in that case between the two environments?

Comment: No, `INT_MAX` is the maximum value of an `int`. For the maximum value of an `unsigned long long`, use `ULLONG_MAX`. But there is no guarantee that this will differ between the two "environments". It might differ, or not, depending on the situation (Windows, Linux, which compiler, etc)