# Negative numeric string (e.g. "-10") to unsigned short

Tags: c++

Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <algorithm>
using std::cerr;
using std::cout;
using std::stringstream;
using std::string;
using std::for_each;

void convert(const string& a_value)
{
    unsigned short i;
    if (stringstream(a_value) >> i)
        cout << a_value << " converted to " << i << ".\n";
    else
        cerr << a_value << " failed to convert.\n";
}

int main()
{
    string inputs[] = { "abc", "10", "999999999999999999999", "-10", "0" };
    for_each(inputs, inputs + (sizeof(inputs)/sizeof(inputs[0])), convert);
    return 0;
}
```

Output from Visual Studio Compiler (v7, v8, v9, v10):

```
abc failed to convert.
10 converted to 10.
999999999999999999999 failed to convert.
-10 converted to 65526.
0 converted to 0.
```

Output from g++ (v4.1.2, [v4.3.4](http://ideone.com/T2sMF3)):

```
abc failed to convert.
10 converted to 10.
999999999999999999999 failed to convert.
-10 failed to convert.
0 converted to 0.
```

I expected the `"-10"` to fail to be converted to an `unsigned short` but it succeeds with the VC compilers. Is this a:

- bug in the VC compilers ?
- bug in the GNU compilers and I have an incorrect expectation ?
- an implementation defined behaviour ?

Comment: It wraps. Your unsigned short is 16 bit. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2760502/question-about-c-behaviour-for-unsigned-integer-underflow

Comment: Garbage in / garbage out -- if you care about string validity, then test it before converting.

Comment: @paddy It is defined behavior. Found a better SO question that has more info than first dup http://stackoverflow.com/questions/50605/signed-to-unsigned-conversion-in-c-is-it-always-safe

Comment: @BrianRoach, I can see that it wraps but I, possibly incorrectly, expected the stream `operator>>` to not do that and fail.

Comment: @hmjd - see the two other SO questions I linked, it's a defined behavior in assignment, so I don't think it should be unexpected with the stream operator.

Comment: @paddy, my expectation is garbage in nothing out and to be informed of the failure. The program tests other garbage inputs and they fail to be converted as expected.

Comment: Hey Brian, I wasn't referring to your comment about wrapping.  Of course it wrapped.  Those links you gave have nothing to do with reading from streams.  The OP wants to know whether reading a negative value into an unsigned from a stringstream has defined behaviour.  I don't know, and cannot answer, but in general my philosophy is: test your inputs when it matters.  It's very simple to do basic validation on the characters of an integer string before converting it.

Comment: @paddy The basic philosophy in this case is to use the `istream` to do the testing.  He should probably declare the `std::istringstream` before the if, and use something like `if ( stream >> i >> std::ws && stream.get() == EOF )`, but that _should_ be sufficient checking.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer depends on what version of C++ you are using.  C++03 and
earlier required the input to conform to what `sscanf` does (using here
the `"%hi"` input specifier), and `sscanf` reads an integral value into
a (signed) short, with no overflow detection; the results are then
assigned (with implicit conversion) to your `unsigned short`.  C++11
requires the equivalent of calling `strtoull`, which doesn't allow the
`-` sign, and requires an error in case of overflow (which is undefined
behavior in `sscanf`, and thus C++03).

In practice, all reasonable implementations of C++03 did check for
overlow, and the "undefined behavior" in such cases corresponded to that
which is now required.  On the other hand, they were *required* to
accept the minus sign, which is now (logically) forbidden.

EDIT (correction):
On rereading the requirements of `strtoull`, I find that it does require accepting the minus sign.  So as stupid as it seems, the standard does require input to an unsigned integral type to accept the minus sign.  (Note too that the behavior of `strtoull` depends on the global C locale, which may accept additional posibilities.)

EDIT (further clarification):
As ectamur points out, this should be an error (in C++11), because `(unsigned long long)( -10 )` will be too large to be represented in an `unsigned short`.  On the other hand, it is still undefined behavior in pre-C++03 (which is perhaps what VC++ is conforming to---so whatever they do is "correct").

Answer (score 3):

g++ is correct.  The arithmetic extractors for unsigned integer types are defined in 27.7.2.2.2p1 as depending on `num_get<>`; 22.4.2.1.2p3 states that:

> Stage 3: The sequence of `char`s accumulated in stage 2 (the field) is converted to a numeric value by the rules of [...] — For an unsigned integer value, the function `strtoull`.

and that the number stored should be

> — the most positive representable value, if the field represents a value too large positive to be represented in `val`. `ios_base::failbit` is assigned to `err`.

On the operation of `strtoull`, C++ defers to C, which is a little unclear on the result of trying to convert a negative-sign field with `strtoull`; it states that "*the value resulting from the conversion is negated (in the return type)*", which for `unsigned long long` would result in sign wrap (to `ULONGLONG_MAX - 10 + 1`).

So `strtoull` returns a value too large to be representable in `unsigned short`, and `num_get` is required to store `USHORT_MAX` and set the fail bit.

On the other hand, 22.4.2.1.2p3 also states that the number stored should be (my emphasis):

> — the most negative representable value **or zero for an unsigned integer type**, if the field represents a value too large negative to be represented in `val`. `ios_base::failbit` is assigned to `err`.

The presence of this clause indicates that the rules of `strtoull` are not to be followed strictly for a field with negative sign; under this interpretation `num_get` is required to store `0` and set the fail bit.

In either case the conversion is required to fail.

Comment: Good point about the overflow.  (I rather suspect that there is still some unintentional behavior in the C++ standard here.  Why should `"-10"` be acceptable when inputting to a `unsigned long long`, but not to other unsigned types?)

Comment: For reference of future visitors, this is open issue [LWG 1169](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/lwg-active.html#1169)