# Is there any better way to calculate (n * 8 + 3) / 5?

Tags: c

I need to take a `size_t volume` and calculate this result in a `size_t`:

```
size_t next = (volume * 8 + 3) / 5
```

If this result would overflow a `size_t` then `next` should be zero. The problem is of course that `volume * 8 + 3` can overflow while the entire result fits in a `size_t`.

At the moment I am splitting out the last 4 bits of `volume` and performing the multiplication, addition, and division separately. My question is: **Can I do better than what I have so far if there is no type larger than `size_t`?**

```
size_t next_volume(size_t volume) {
  // check if the numerator will overflow size_t
  if (volume > (SIZE_MAX - 3) / 8) {
    size_t lower, upper;

    // multiply lower 4 bits by 8 and add 3
    lower = ((volume & 0xF) * 8) + 3;
    // downshift the rest and multiply by 8
    upper = (volume >> 4) * 8;

    // divide upper remainder and lower by 5
    lower = ((upper % 5 << 4) + lower) / 5;

    // divide upper by 5
    upper = upper / 5;

    // ensure the sum will not overflow size_t
    if (upper + (lower >> 4) > SIZE_MAX >> 4)
      return 0;

    return (upper << 4) + lower;
  } else return (volume * 8 + 3) / 5;
}
```

There might be some errors in that code. I haven't put it through extensive testing yet but I believe all the main ideas are there.

Comment: @meaning-matters: Let's assume I want to stick to integer operations only.

Comment: You are correct.  Thanks for commenting, I removed my answer.  (Very good question)

Comment: going through a lot of operations like that may be slower than letting the compiler optimize out the original expression. Did you measure the performance?

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc: The problem is that the original expression doesn't work. `volume * 8` might overflow `size_t` before the division by 5 takes place. The compiler can't deal with this directly.

Comment: oops I didn't notice about overflow. But there are also many ways to detect overflow in C

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let `vol1 = volume % 5`, `vol2 = volume - vol1`. vol2 is divisible by 5, therefore mathematically (vol2 * 8) / 5 = (vol2 / 5) * 8, so you get the correct result as

```
size_t vol1 = volume % 5;
size_t vol2 = volume - vol1;
size_t result = (vol2 / 5) * 8 + (vol1 * 8 + 3) / 5
```

Obviously you will get an overflow if the result doesn't fit into size_t, but not if there is an overflow anywhere in the calculation. Since you multiply by 8/5, in case of an overflow the result will be about 0.6 * volume < volume, so you can return

```
return result < volume ? (size_t) -1 : result;
```

which is surely better than returning 0.

Comment: size_t is unsigned, so returning -1 is undefined behaviour. I think 0 is better.

Comment: @WouterVerhelst: Do you have a citation for that (hint: you don't, it's perfectly defined)?

Comment: As far as I can tell, `vol2` is unneeded: `volume/5` is already truncated to an integer value.

Comment: @FredLarson: That question is for C++.  For C: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2760502/question-about-c-behaviour-for-unsigned-integer-underflow (to clarify here, returning `-1` is exactly the same as returning `SIZE_MAX`).

Comment: @StephenCanon: You're right. I neglected to check the tag.