# What happens when you have an infinite loop in c due to an unsigned int variable type

Tags: c, memory, infinite-loop, unsigned

I'm aware that it can never be negative but what happens to the value in memory after it goes "below" 0?

example:

```
unsigned int i = 3;

while(i >=0){
    print("something");
    i=-i;
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8026694/c-unary-minus-operator-behavior-with-unsigned-operands

Comment: You're flipping between `3` (i.e. `0x00000003`) and `-3` (i.e. `0xFFFFFFFD`). Because you're using `unsigned` the latter is _just_ a large _positive_ number. The actual bit pattern is the _same_ regardless of whether you've got `int` or `unsigned int`. It is how it is interpreted by the expression in the `while` that matters. This is "two's complement arithmetic": `-x --> ~x + 1`. That is, invert the bits, and then add 1. With a signed value, the most significant bit (e.g. `0x80000000`) if set means a negative number.

Comment: Unsigned need not use 2's complement arithmetic; that is only the case if `UINT_MAX` is `2^n - 1` (but it need not be) ;)

Comment: @AnttiHaapala: That's all wrong. `UINT_MAX` (or any integer type's max) is required to be one less than a power of two. "Twos complement" is not relevant to unsigned types. They're just modular arithmetic mod a power of two.

Comment: Also the close-as-duplicate is wrong. The candidate duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2760502/question-about-c-behaviour-for-unsigned-integer-underflow is about assignment of a signed value to an unsigned object. This question is about a misunderstanding of unary `-` operator on unsigned operands.

Comment: @R.. yes `UINT_MAX` not `2^n - 1` is not conforming. As for the duplicate, you're correct...

Answer (score 0):

The unary `-` operator on an unsigned operand does not produce a value below zero. It produces a value which, when added to the operand in ordinary integer arithmetic, would yield one plus the maximal value the type can represent.