# Am I correct in figuring out why this while loop is infinite?

Tags: c, while-loop, infinite-loop, unsigned

I wrote a simple program (included below) that takes a 5-digit number, reverses and prints it.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <math.h>
int main(void)
{
        unsigned short num, revnum, digit, count;
        count = 4;
        revnum = 0;
        fprintf(stdout, "Enter a five digit number in range [0 - %hu]: ", USHRT_MAX);
        fscanf(stdin, "%hu", &num);
        while (count >= 0) {
                digit = num % 10;
                num = num / 10;
                revnum += digit * pow(10, count);
                count--;
        }
        fprintf(stdout, "The number with digits reversed is %hu.\n", revnum);
        return 0;
}
```

However the program when run, doesn't return anything post taking input and storing it in the `num` variable. It didn't crash/exit either. There is nothing wrong with the `while` loop's body, so I suspected an infinite loop and wrote a small program just to print out the `count` variable from a similar while loop

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
        unsigned short count;
        count = 4;
        while (count >= 0) {
                printf("%hu", count);
                count--;
        }
        return 0;
}
```

This indeed turns out to be an `infinite` loop... a part of the output is:

> `...300653005530045300353002530015300052999529985299752996529955299452993529925299152990529895298852987529865298552984529835298252981529805297952978529775297652975529745297352972529715297052969529685296752966529655296452963529625296152960529595295852957529565295552954529535295252951529^C`

My assumption is that the culprit is the `count`'s `type` which is `unsigned short`. As this means it can't decrement below 0, so the final `count--` *when `count` already `== 0`* sets its value to `USHRT_MAX` and thus can never terminate the loop. Am I correct?

Comment: Yes, `count` can't be negative, the condition is always true. The details on how it can't be negative, I believe are implementation defined, pending confirmation.

Comment: here's a [standard reference about unsigned underflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2760502/question-about-c-behaviour-for-unsigned-integer-underflow)

Comment: The `count` variable is `unsigned` which means it will always be greater then or equal to zero. Yes your assumption is correct.

Comment: Most compilers will issue a warning when using `>= 0` on an unsigned value.

Comment: @Elijan9 GCC didn't

Comment: Include either `-Wtype-limits` or `-W` when calling gcc to get warnings for this.

Comment: @Elijan9 I did have `-Wall`. So that's not enough to capture this warning?

Comment: @computronium, you can also use `-Wextra` for this one.

Comment: **Never** use `pow` to calculate powers of 10. Just repeated multiplications by 10. Unless of course you're happy with `(int)pow(10, 2)` being 99. This is an error that for some reason pops at least 3 times a week on Stack Overflow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your assumption is correct: being your variable `unsigned` it won't ever be evaluated as negative.

In your case, if you decrement the `count` variable when  it is equal to 0 you get the value 65535 (`USHRT_MAX`).

The trivial solution is getting rid of the `unsigned` keyword:

```
short count = 4;
```

This solution is the best for the basic code provided in the question. Anyway, since in the "real code" could happen that changing the type of the counter is not an option, a check on `count == 0` before decrementing could be the solution (credits to @Elijan9):

```
while (true)
{
    /* ...; */
     if (count == 0)
        break;
    --count;
 }
```

Comment: Or stick with unsigned and compare count to 0 before decrementing it in the loop, e.g. `while (true) { ...; if (count == 0) break; --count; }`

Comment: @Elijan sure, even if it would probably be overkill in this specific case. Also, it is posdible that it's not the actual code but just a MRE

Comment: @Elijan9 I've incorporated you suggestion (and properly _rewarded_ it), in case  the code in the question is not the actual code but just a simplified MRE. Thank you.