# Difference in queue sizes giving arbitrarily large value C++

Tags: c++, c++11, stl, priority-queue, heap

```
#include <iostream>
#include <queue>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    // cout<<"Hello World";

    priority_queue<int> spq;  // max heap
    priority_queue <int, vector<int>, greater<int>> lpq; // min heap
    
    
    spq.push(1);
    
    lpq.push(2);
    lpq.push(3);
    
    
    cout << spq.size() - lpq.size() << endl;
    
    
    return 0;
}
```

This code is giving me un-expectedly very large value of `18446744073709551615`

I am not able to understand the issue here.

Comment: Sizes are unsigned. Subtracting a larger size from a smaller size causes a wrap-around.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2760612/4165552

Comment: @sweenish, understood. type-casting them into int, solved my problem

Comment: I think you may be in [UB](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub) territory.

Comment: @JesperJuhl Unsigned integer overflow is defined, signed is not

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have unsigned integer wrap-around.

`spq.size()` is `1`, `lpq.size()` is `2`.

So when you do `1 - 2`, since you're using unsigned numbers, you don't end up in the negatives, you instead wrap around to the *largest* unsigned number you have, `18446744073709551615`.